# Avoiding conflicts with elastic upsert

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am having an issue trying to implement optimistic locking when executing a document upsert.

I followed all the guides, however I am getting the following error:

```
Validation Failed: 1: compare and write operations can not be used with upsert;
```

I can trace this error back to this [validate](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/update/UpdateRequest.java#L175) method, however I cannot find an explanation as to why this cannot be done nor HOW to do an upsert without running into conflicts.

Here's where I am getting the error in my code:

```
private UpdateResponse doAction(UUID esId, List<Comment> comments, dSeqNoPrimaryTerm seqPrimNo, String indexName) {
        UpdateResponse response = null;
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("comments", comments);
        Builder builder = UpdateQuery
                .builder(esId.toString())
                .withDocAsUpsert(true)
                .withDocument(Document.from(params))
                .withRefresh(Refresh.True);
        if (seqPrimNo != null) {
            builder.withIfSeqNo((int) seqPrimNo.getSequenceNumber());
            builder.withIfPrimaryTerm((int) seqPrimNo.getPrimaryTerm());
        }
        UpdateQuery query = builder.build();
        response = elasticsearchTemplate.update(query, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName));  // <-- ERRORS HERE
        return response;
    }
```

Does that mean that we cannot do optimistic locking when doing an upsert?  What am I missing?